# Can I check if a context already has timeout set?

Tags: go

I have a custom http client, which has a default timeout value.  The code is like this:

```
type Client struct {
  *http.Client
  timeout time.Duration
}

func (c *Client) Send(ctx context.Context, r *http.Request) (int, []byte, error) {
  // If ctx has timeout set, then don't change it.
  // Otherwise, create new context with ctx.WithTimeout(c.timeout)
}
```

How can I check if `ctx` has timeout set or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the bool return value from [`context.Deadline`](https://godoc.org/context#Context):

> Deadline returns the time when work done on behalf of this context
>   should be canceled. Deadline returns ok==false when no deadline is
>   set. Successive calls to Deadline return the same results.
>
> ```
> Deadline() (deadline time.Time, ok bool)
> ```

```
func (c *Client) Send(ctx context.Context, r *http.Request) (int, []byte, error) {
    if _, deadlineSet := ctx.Deadline(); !deadlineSet {
        ctx, _ = context.WithTimeout(ctx, c.timeout)
    }
}
```